# Get the file size of a URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, open-uri

Here is a link:
"https://www.reddit.com".

While requiring "open-uri" in a ruby file the same link responds with 2 different file sizes
when using these 2 methods:

p URI.open("https://www.reddit.com").size

p open("https://www.reddit.com").size

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Have you looked at what each is actually returning before you call #size on the String?

Comment: The discrepancy in file sizes when using the two methods in Ruby (URI.open and open) is due to the way they handle the HTTP request.

    URI.open("https://www.reddit.com").size:
    The URI.open method uses the open-uri library, which is part of Ruby's standard library. When you use URI.open, it internally opens the URL and retrieves the content as a temporary file before calculating the size. This means it first downloads the entire content and then provides the size of the downloaded file. This is why you get the actual size of the content in this case.

Comment: .....
    open("https://www.reddit.com").size:
    The open method here comes from the open-uri library as well. However, the behavior is slightly different. When using open without explicitly specifying URI, it calls the open method from the Kernel module, which in turn delegates the request to the URI.open method. However, the crucial difference here is that the content is not downloaded as a temporary file first. Instead, the response is read in chunks to determine the size without downloading the entire content. ...

Comment: This method might return a smaller file size since it doesn't take into account the entire content's size, especially if the server is sending the response in chunks.

Comment: What ruby version are you using? `URI::open` via `Kernel#open` was deprecated in 2.7 and removed in 3.0.

Comment: Reddit seems to deliver different pages, maybe based on server-side browser sniffing or just due to a load balancer. When requesting `https://www.reddit.com` outside of a regular browser e.g. using `curl` or Ruby's `URI.open`, I keep getting random/different pages which would explain the varying file sizes.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. Currently using ruby 2.6.1.  While using a different site I figured out open(url) gives the response of the webpage and not it's size.